# Comparing the prime spectra of $\mathbb{Q}[x],\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I understand that $\mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{Q}[x]=\{(0),(f(x)): f(x)\mbox{ is an irreducible polynomial}\}.$ An argument is the following one: $(0)$ is prime because $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is an integral domain. Since $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a PID (and hence UFD) an ideal $(f(x))$ is prime iff $f(x)$ is prime iff $f(x)$ is irreducible.

I have read that $\mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{R}[x]=\{(0),(x-a),(g(x)): a\in \mathbb{R}, \ g(x)\mbox{ is an irreducible polynomial of degree 2}\}.$ I understand $(0)$ is prime because $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is integral, and also understand $(x-a)$ is prime (in fact maximal) because the map $$\mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{R}, \ h(x) \mapsto h(a)$$ 
has kernel $(x-a)$. Now I can use the first isomorphism Theorem. For the last part, just as in $\mathbb{Spec}\mathbb{Q}[x]$ case, $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a PID (and hence UFD), thus an ideal $(g(x)) \subset \mathbb{R}[x]$ is prime iff $g(x)$ is prime iff $g(x)$ is irreducible. **My question 1): why $g(x)$ should be of degree exactly 2?** **I don`t understand what properties of $\mathbb{R}$ creates this restriction, the one that is not in $\mathbb{Q}[x].$**

I think I understand the $\mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x]$ case well, namely $\mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x]=\{(0),(x-a):a\in \mathbb{C}\}.$ Just as above $(h(x))\subset \mathbb{C}[x]$ is prime iff $h(x)$ is prime iff $h(x)$ is irreducible. But $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed, hence $h(x) = x-a$ for some $a \in \mathbb{C}.$ In fact this argument holds for $\mathrm{Spec}k[x]$, for any algebraically closed field $k$.

My final question (besides the one above) is what is the difference between these three prime spectra in geometric terms?

Comment: you know that the roots of a real polynomial are real or complex conjugates (obvious that if $P(a+ib) = 0$ then $P(a-ib) = 0$), so a real polynomial of degree 4 has 0,1 or 2 pairs of complex conjugate roots. in every case it is not irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x]$, since $(x-a)(x-\overline{a}) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$. The same argument shows what Arthur says below

Comment: Any polynomial of degree $3$ or higher in $\Bbb R[x]$ is reducible over $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The prime spectrum of $k[x]$ is $(0)$ and $(f(x))$ for irreducible polynomials $f$ for any field $k$. When $k = \mathbb{R}$, the irreducible polynomials are precisely the linear polynomials and the quadratic polynomials with no real roots, by the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Geometrically, you can think of the point $(f(x))$ as describing the set of all of its roots, as an orbit of the action of the Galois group $G = \text{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)$ on the points of the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1$ over $\bar{k}$.

Comment: (since $k[x]$ is automatically a PID when $k$ is a field) can you explain your "geometrically" ? you consider the Galois group of the algebraic closure, but then what ?

Comment: @user1952009: there are a couple of different things you might want me to explain. Can you be more specific?

Comment: the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1$ ? I can see how $Gal(\overline{k}/k)$ acts on the roots, let's say it acts on some $n$-upples of (complex algebraic when $k = \mathbb{Q}$) points

Comment: @user1952009: I don't understand your question. Are you asking what the affine line is? There are several different possible answers in increasing levels of sophistication. Are you familiar with the geometric interpretation of $\text{Spec } \mathbb{C}[x]$ as being the "complex line" $\mathbb{C}$? Then you can think about $\text{Spec } \mathbb{R}[x]$ as being orbits of complex conjugation acting on $\mathbb{C}$, and the above generalizes this observation to an arbitrary field in place of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The reason I want to say "the points of the affine line over $\bar{k}$," which is just another way of saying "$\bar{k}$," is that if I said $\bar{k}$ you might think I care about the ring structure, but in fact I only care about the action of the Galois group in this discussion.

Comment: A question : in what space do you think to the algebraic closure and its $Gal$ as being in, in general ? for $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ I think to it as being in $\mathbb{C}$, but it doesn't help for $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$. And for $k = \mathbb{F}_p$ it is even more abstract, and it is hard to visualise $\overline{k}$

Comment: I pretend that the algebraic closure of every field looks like $\mathbb{C}$. This at least works okay in characteristic $0$.