# Picture of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{R}[x])$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-schemes

Follow-up to [Comparing the prime spectra of $\mathbb{Q}[x],\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1856918/326036). I'm trying to draw a picture of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{R}[x])$.

I've already drawn a picture of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x]) = \{(0)\} \cup \{(x - \alpha) \mid \alpha \in \mathbb{C}\}$ as a complex plane plus the generic point $(0)$:

[image: Spec(C[x])]

Now, $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{R}[x]) = \{(0)\} \cup \{(p) \mid p \text{ irreducible in }\mathbb{R}\}$.
At first, I thought of identifying each irreducible polynomial with a complex root, but this isn't well-defined as some irreducible polynomials will have more than one root.
But the irreducibles in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ are linear polynomials and quadratics with no real root, and the latter have two conjugate complex roots.
So I thought we can represent this spectrum as the upper half of the complex plane, identifying each quadratic irreducible with its complex root with positive imaginary part, as follows:

[image: Spec(R[x])]

Is this an accurate picture?

Comment: FWIW upper half plane is what I would use. The lower half plane would do equally well (or some perverse combination thereof, possibly invoking axiom of choice). But we have grown to prefer the upper half plane :-)

Comment: By the way, we also have an algebraic-geometry tag here on MSE, which would be appropriate to use on your future algebraic geometry questions. I've added it for you this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. More generally, for a Galois extension $k\subset K$, one can think of the natural map $\Bbb A^n_K\to\Bbb A^n_k$ coming from the natural inclusion $k[t_1,\cdots,t_n]\to K[t_1,\cdots,t_n]$ as the quotient by the Galois action, which is what you've done here: folded the complex plane over the real axis.